# How does Function Module SPELL_AMOUNT converts number to string variables?

Tags: abap

I am trying to understand the source code of function module SPELL_AMOUNT in SAP, which converts number, amount, or currency representation into letters. For example, '568' will be converted to FIVE HUNDRED AND SIXTY EIGHT.

However, when I use SE37 to read the source code of the FM, I could not find the piece of code which indicates that the number is converted to string. For instance, `IF int_decimal = 10. APPEND "TEN" INTO in_word`.

Please explain if you have access to ABAP source code

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The function module uses values stored in **database table `T015Z`** ('Digits and numbers in words').
There, numbers in different units are mapped to words in different languages.
[image]

See include `LF017F01`, form `ziffern_in_worten` (German for 'numbers in words').
The table is read in FORM `t015z_lesen` into the internal table of the same name (`t015z`).
After fetching this data it is processed to get the text for the complete number/amount.
See these three subroutine calls:

```
  PERFORM ziffern_in_worten.   "Get data from the database, convert numbers to words
  PERFORM betrag_in_worten.    "Get amount in words
  PERFORM nachkomma_in_worten. "Get decimal part in words
```

[image]

Comment: There are also some technical information in the note [939145 - SPELL_AMOUNT: What it can do and what it can't](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/939145/E), including the description of the table T015Z.